# C# load cshtml into modal with JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to load the content from one page into a modal on another page on the click of a button, but it is also loading in the content from the __Layout page. I have tried calling a controller using:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.container').load('/Home/MyPage');
})


<div class="container"></div>
```

However, I cannot get it to load in solely what is in the MyPage.cshtml file. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below snippet on top of `MyPage.cshtml` to avoid loading with the layout page.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```